# DataAdapter does not delete database row

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataadapter, .net-3.5

I'm working on a very old project with .Net Framework 3.5 using `DataSets` and SQL Server. So I need to do something.

I'm facing a problem with deleting rows from database. Here is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TypedDataSetTest.UsersDataSetTableAdapters;

namespace TypedDataSetTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var userAdapter = new UserTableAdapter())
            {
                var users = userAdapter.GetData();

                userAdapter.DeleteAll();
                users.Clear();    

                PopulateUsers(users, userAdapter);
                PrintData(users);

                var user1 = users.Single(user => user.Name == "user1");
                user1.Delete();
                user1.AcceptChanges();
                //users.AcceptChanges();
                //userAdapter.Update(user1);

                var user2 = users.Single(user => user.Name == "user2");
                user2.Name = "user3";
                //mary.AcceptChanges();
                //users.AcceptChanges();
                //userAdapter.Update(user2);

                userAdapter.Update(users);

                PrintData(users);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void PrintData(UsersDataSet.UserDataTable users)
        {
            users.ToList().ForEach(user => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3:dd/MM/yyyy} {4}", user.Id, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Field<string>("Name")) ? "" : user.Field<string>("Name"), user.Surname, user.Field<DateTime?>("BirthDate").GetValueOrDefault(), user.TIN));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        private static void PopulateUsers(UsersDataSet.UserDataTable users, UserTableAdapter userAdapter)
        {
            var user1 = users.NewUserRow();
            user1.Name = "user1";
            user1.Surname = "user1 surname";
            user1.BirthDate = new DateTime(1970, 12, 03);
            user1.TIN = "123123";

            var user2 = users.NewUserRow();
            user2.Name = "user2";
            user2.Surname = "user2 surname";
            user2.BirthDate = new DateTime(1974, 2, 14);
            user2.TIN = "456456";

            var newUsers = new UsersDataSet.UserRow[] { user1, user2 };
            userAdapter.Connection.Open();

            newUsers.ToList().ForEach(user =>
            {
                if (userAdapter.InsertUser(user) > 0)
                {
                    users.AddUserRow(user);
                    users.AcceptChanges();
                }                
            });

            userAdapter.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

All database actions are performed through stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_Delete]
    (@Id INT)
AS
    --set nocount on;
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[User] 
    WHERE (Id = @Id);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_DeleteAll]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[User];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_Insert](
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Surname NVARCHAR(50),
    @BirthDate DATETIM2(7),
    @TIN NVARCHAR(50))
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([Name], [Surname], [BirthDate], [TIN])
    VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @BirthDate, @TIN);

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();   
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_SelectAll]
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT    
        [Id], [Name], [Surname], [BirthDate], [TIN]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[User];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_Update]
    (@Id INT,
     @Name NVARCHAR(50),
     @Surname NVARCHAR(50),
     @BirthDate DATETIME2(7),
     @TIN NVARCHAR(50))
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     UPDATE [dbo].[User]
     SET [Name] = @Name,
         [Surname] = @Surname,
         [BirthDate] = @BirthDate,
         [TIN] = @TIN
     WHERE (Id = @Id)
GO
```

Also here is my xsd and table-adapter info, all by the book(I think):

[image]

This code seems to work on console, `user1` is deleted from the DataTable and `user2` name is changed to "user3".

But in database table, only the change of name is persisted. `User1` was not deleted.

If I call `userAdapter.Update(user1);` everything is fine. I've tried several things found on Internet but nothing seems to work.

It looks like `userAdapter` cannot locate the `DeleteCommand` for the `user1` row. There is no exception, just it does not delete it from the database.

Am I missing something? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This code works fine:

```
using (var userAdapter = new UserTableAdapter())
            {
                var users = userAdapter.GetData();

                userAdapter.DeleteAll();
                users.Clear();    

                PopulateUsers(users, userAdapter);
                PrintData(users);

                var user1 = users.Single(user => user.Name == "user1");
                var user2 = users.Single(user => user.Name == "user2");

                user1.Delete(); 
                user2.Name = "user3";

                userAdapter.Update(users);

                PrintData(users);
            }
```

In the previous version, I could not locate `user2` if `user1` was "marked" as to-delete so I called `AcceptChanges` to be able to iterate through `users` data-table to get `user2`. Calling `user1.AcceptChanges();` changed the status of `user1` row, so there is no to-delete information.

So everything is fine!